# css transition how to make mouseout effect

Tags: html, css, hover, css-transitions

I am trying to figure out a way to make the black blob go back smoothly as you're dragging the cursor off it. Better yet I was wondering if its possible to make the blob disappear from left to right using css. Also, do you have an idea on how to make the text turn white as the blob goes over them? Thank you so much for help!

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 30px 0;
  /*background-color: red;*/
}

li {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: .71em;
}

ul li i {
  margin-left: 7px;
}

li a {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

li a::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0%;
  height: 1.3em;
  background-color: black;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: width .2s;
}

li a:hover::before {
  width: 100%;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font- 
    awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>CSS & HTML NAVIGATION</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" title="home">home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="text">text</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="image">image</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="slider">slider<i class="fa fa-angle-down" title="slider"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="html">html<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="css">css</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use visibility since you already set 0% to width. You can also adjust the position to have a left to right transtion. For the color, simply add another hover declarion on the `a`:

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 30px 0;
  /*background-color: red;*/
}

li {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: .71em;
}

ul li i {
  margin-left: 7px;
}

li a {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

li a::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 0%;
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
  height: 1.3em;
  background-color: black;
  transition: width .2s, left .2s .2s, right .2s .2s;
}

li a:hover::before {
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: auto;
}

li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" title="home">home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" title="text">text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" title="image">image</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" title="slider">slider<i class="fa fa-angle-down" title="slider"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" title="html">html<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" title="css">css</a></li>
</ul>
```

You can also simplify your code using gradient:

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 30px 0;
  /*background-color: red;*/
}

li {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: .71em;
}

ul li i {
  margin-left: 7px;
}

li a {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  background: linear-gradient(#000, #000) left/0% 100% no-repeat;
  transition: 
    color 0.2s,
    background-size 0.2s, 
    background-position 0.2s 0.2s;
}

li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-position: right;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" title="home">home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" title="text">text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" title="image">image</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" title="slider">slider<i class="fa fa-angle-down" title="slider"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" title="html">html<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" title="css">css</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

i have updated your css code. hope this helps you:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 30px 0;
  /*background-color: red;*/
}

li {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: .71em;
}

ul li i {
  margin-left: 7px;
}

li a {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition-property: color;
  transition-property: color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

li a::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #000;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 50%;
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

li a:hover:before,
li a:focus:before,
li a:active:before {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

li a:hover::before {
  width: 100%;
  visibility: visible;
}

li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font- 
    awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>CSS & HTML NAVIGATION</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" title="home">home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="text">text</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="image">image</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="slider">slider<i class="fa fa-angle-down" title="slider"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="html">html<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="css">css</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```